# Callback references as arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

```
var clientData = {
    id: 1969,
    fullName: "Not Set",
    setUserName: function (firstName, lastName)  {
      clientData.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
      console.log(clientData.fullName);
    }
};

function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback)  {  
  //why can't I say clientData.callback (firstName, lastName); instead
  callback (firstName, lastName);
}

getUserInput ("Peter", "Pan", clientData.setUserName);
```

As is commented in the code, why can't I say `clientData.callback (firstName, lastName);` if what the callback argument is referencing *is* the function that should be accessible from clientData with dot access? If clientData.setUserName is just a reference to a function object, I shouldn't be accidentally saying clientData.clientData.setUsername with my commented code, right?

I'm a beginner, and because it's not working I'm sure I'm thinking of something wrong.

Comment: You can say `clientData.setUserName()`, you cannot say `clientData.callback()` - there is no such method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientData.callback` would **literally** try to access property `callback` on `clientData`. Think about `clientData.callback` being equivalent to `clientData['callback']`.

What comes after the `.` is not treated as a variable. Even if it were, the value of `callback` is a *function*. You can't use a function as *property name*. Property names are *strings*.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a function, think of the arguments as variables used in the function. When you do:

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback)
```

and you call it with:

```
getUserInput ("Peter", "Pan", clientData.setUserName);
```

What implicitly happens at the top of the function is:

```
var firstName = "Peter";
var lastName = "Pan";
var callback = clientData.setUserName
```

Whatever you pass in as `callback` is referenced inside the function as `callback`. So if you pass in `clientData.setUserName`, it doesn't matter that it belongs to an object called `clientData` - it is still referred to as `callback` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName)  {  
  clientData.setUserName (firstName, lastName);
}
```